# Sockets in .NET - Getting started with a multithreaded server

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, clients

Networking in C# is something I am relatively new to and so I was wondering how to get started with it for a particular project.

Ultimately, I want to develop a server which can have as many as one thousand clients connected to it concurrently (TCP protocol).

I understand creating a new thread for each client would be potentially quite inefficient, especially with the memory overhead of each thread once passing 100 clients for example.

So simply, what I am asking is, could anyone suggest anywhere I could find out more about getting started with developing 'multithreaded' servers for many clients.

(Please add a comment if this question is too broad.)

Comment: It is not merely a C# (.NET) API question by nature. See http://smallvoid.com/article/winnt-tcpip-max-limit.html for a good albeit a bit aged summary of aspects which might spoil your plans. Also, given that in Windows a lot of system resources are of native type ``HANDLE`` (they are waitable) in more or less obvious fashion, you can use a thread pool easily to manage multiple connections. The 1 thread per connection approach is not your only option. Also, you might want to look up what a ``completion port`` is good for, as that will give you fresh ideas how to do what you try to do.

Answer (score 2):

You may give a try for [`SignalR`](https://www.asp.net/signalr) for sockets.

> What is `SignalR`?
>   ASP.NET SignalR is a library for ASP.NET developers that simplifies the process of adding real-time web functionality to applications. Real-time web functionality is the ability to have server code push content to connected clients instantly as it becomes available, rather than having the server wait for a client to request new data.
>   ...
>   `SignalR` provides a simple API for creating server-to-client remote procedure calls (RPC) that call `JavaScript` functions in client browsers (and other client platforms) from server-side .NET code. `SignalR` also includes API for connection management (for instance, connect and disconnect events), and grouping connections.

[image]

To implement a server you need to derive from `Hub` class:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
namespace SignalRChat
{
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public void Send(string name, string message)
        {
            // Call the broadcastMessage method to update clients.
            Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message);
        }
    }
}
```

And from client side javascript is like this:

```
var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (name, message) {
  // interact with server
}
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
        // Call the Send method on the hub. 
        chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
        // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment. 
        $('#message').val('').focus();
    });
});
```

[Supported Platforms for `SignalR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/supported-platforms) are:

- Server side

  - Windows Server 2012
  - Windows Server 2008 r2
  - Windows 8
  - Windows 7
  - Windows Azure
- Client side

  - Browsers
  - Microsoft Internet Explorer versions 8, 9, 10, and 11. Modern, Desktop, and Mobile versions are supported.
  - Mozilla Firefox: current version - 1, both Windows and Mac versions.
  - Google Chrome: current version - 1, both Windows and Mac versions.
  - Safari: current version - 1, both Mac and iOS versions.
  - Opera: current version - 1, Windows only.
  - Android browser
  - Windows Desktop and Silverlight Applications
  - Applications using .NET 4 are supported on Windows XP SP3 or later.
  - Applications using .NET Framework 4.5 are supported on Windows Vista or later.
  - Windows Store and Windows Phone 8 Applications

[Default performance constants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/performance/signalr-performance) do cover your limitations for up to 1000 simultaneous requests.

Comment: Wasnt really what I was looking for, however, I might keep that in mind for future. Thanks. However, I have sorted everything now and no longer need an answer to my question :)

Comment: Then you should answer your question by yourself to provide a solution to others